# How to grouping array values or categorize values in array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[N];
int cons75 = 0, cons40 = 0, below40 = 0, i;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (arr[i] >= 75) {
        cons75++;

    } else if (arr[i] < 75 && arr[i] >= 40) {
        cons40++;
    } else {
        below40++;
    }

}
Console.WriteLine(cons75);
Console.WriteLine(cons40);
Console.WriteLine(below40);
Console.ReadKey();
```

My inputs are:

```
10
3
8
23
98
34
75
23
87
56
78
```

I want to categories or grouping Scores consists of scores above 75, second consist scores between 40 to 75, and third consists of scores less than 40
and my expected output is:

```
4
1
5
```

What i got is:

```
3
1
6
```

whats wrong in these

Comment: The expected output is wrong. Based on your input, you have 6 numbers that are less than 40: 10,3,8,23,34,23. The same hold for the rest. you have 3 numbers greater than 75: 98, 87, 78 and you have 1 number between 40 and 75: 75. So your program works as it is expected.

Comment: @Christos what about 56? any way the program looks fine. Are you sure thats the input?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten you are correct. My bad...thanks for mentioning this. However, as you also said the program looks fine. So given than input I don't see how the expected output is the one OP expects. Regarding the 56, it might be a mistake.

Comment: By the way, i have just tried it and the output is as expected. Probably just a typo in the input

Comment: @Christos You must not count the first input of 10, because that only defines how many numbers should be read afterwards. Then you have 5 numbers (3,8,23,34,23) which are < 40, one number (56) which is >= 40 and < 75 and you have 4 numbers (98, 75, 87, 87) which are >= 75 so the expected output is correct. And the source as it is shown here works correct and gives the expected result.

Comment: Are you sure, you are inputting exactly these values and you are showing us exactly the code you are running? The code shown above is correct and for the given input it gives the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

Try code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] groups = { 75, 40, 0 };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] input = { 10, 3, 8, 23, 98, 34, 75, 23, 87, 56, 78 };

            List<List<int>> results = input.GroupBy(x => GetGroup(x)).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
        }
        static int GetGroup(int number)
        {

            int index = -1;
            while (number < groups[++index]) ;
            return index;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this code better than the OP? I think that `10` is the input for number of items (`N` in the OP's code)

Comment: First of all, this code is not equivalent to the OP's code. And second it's FAR more complicated then the OP's code.  I needed to read it twice to understand what's going on.

Comment: Why is this more complicated?  The linq is much faster than a for loop.  It is more understandable then the users spaghetti code.

Comment: 1) Why do you think, linq is much faster than a for loop? 2) How would your approach handle user input? 3) Do you really believe your `GetGroup()` and using it in a `GroupBy` is more understandable than a simple `if() elseif() else` ???

Comment: 4) Your code isn't even giving a result. For that, you will have to traverse the resulting `List<List<int>>` another time. So it's quite save to assume, that your approach uses more time and more memory and is much more difficult to understand, especially for a beginner

Comment: 5) It's bad practice on SO to just say "try this code" without any explanation, why it would be better

Comment: My code is easy to understand and groups the value instead of just getting a count of each and runs in the same time.  If I use : List<int> results = arr.GroupBy(x => GetGroup(x)).Select(x => x.Count()).ToList(); my code runs faster.

Comment: You have any proof for that or is that just your opinion. Define "faster". And for a beginner, which OP obviously is, I doubt, your code is easy to understand. He would have to know about linq, grouping, understand your grouping function and so on and so forth.

Comment: Your approach is, without any question, more flexible and general. But I go with Don Knuth "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: BTW out of curiosity I created the following fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/iGp2G0 For 800000 items, your approach takes about twice or thrice the time of OP's method. Running on a local machine for 20 million items, it took even four times longer ...

Comment: You are not comparing apples to apples.  When my code get done you have the number separated into three group which the op code doesn't do.  The title of the posting is : "How to grouping array values or categorize values in array".  The OP only counted and did not do what the title said.

Comment: You said " List<int> results = arr.GroupBy(x => GetGroup(x)).Select(x => x.Count()).ToList(); my code runs faster. " and that's excactly what the fiddle is doing. OP has it in three different variables. would be quite easy, to make a list out of that, don't you think?

Comment: And when looking at the "expected output" from OP, just counting the values for the three categories seems enough for now.

Comment: See this updated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/MyOwh2 which builds lists of values in the for loop too. Unfortunately, dotnetfiddle's memory restictions don't allow to run examples big enough to show the difference, but on my local machine, the for loop is still 2-3 times as faster than the linq variant.

Comment: Here is another example of the bad policies of this website that I'm constantly complaining about.  The site requires the OP to post cost even if it is not what they really want.  I posted a solution based on the OPs requirements to Group the values.  Now people are making ridiculous comments that my code is wrong because it doesn't match the OPs code which only counts instead of Grouping that the OP really wants.

Comment: 1) I clearly showed, that your claim "LINQ is faster than a for loop" is wrong, even for the grouping case. 2) How do you know, what the op really wants? I assume a given input and expected output to better reflect the op's requirements, than a verbal description, in a language that is clearly not the op's native language (and neither is it mine). If there are  discrepancies between code and description one should ask for clarification. 3) Silently assuming different requirements and posting code without any explanation does not help anyone finding their error (especially, if there is none)

Comment: Based on the OP input and expected output they are not needed. Your approach provides a solution for a different problem. It's not "wrong" to use them for calculation. But they add an unneeded complexity (in readability of the code and in space and time consumption) to the solution.